# Angularjs and www resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an issue where my site doesn't load unless the user enters `www`. For example, if the user enters mysite.com (as opposed to www.mysite.com, or http://www.mysite.com), then my site only partially loads. I suspect this is either an issue with my use of angularjs or angular ui-router. My site has an html wrapper template that is used on every page. That is what is being loaded if the user doesn't enter `www`, but the template partial that should be inserted into that particular page isn't being loaded unless `www` is entered. For example, www.mysite.com/page would consist of my html wrapper template AND a page.html template partial that is supposed to be inserted into the html wrapper template, but page.html is only being loaded if the user enters `www`. Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably related to your web server configuration.  Can you look in the browser debugger and see what HTTP calls are failing?

Comment: As a side note, it's not a good idea to use both domains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109362/784331

Comment: The problem is that USERS will use both domains, sometimes entering mysite.com and sometimes entering www.mysite.com.