# Why does php's mail() want to deliver to the second specified MX record?

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

This is very similar to this problem:

[sendmail and MX records when mail server is not on web host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322659/sendmail-and-mx-records-when-mail-server-is-not-on-web-host)

I have a php script on an IIS server called example.org.  It sends mail() to somedude@example.com, which goes to a spam appliance and on to their Exchange server, but the mail never gets through.  When I look in the logs there's an SMTP error saying user unknown or something, but the main point is that it's throwing an error as it's using the server specified in the second MX record, rather than the primary one.  Consistantly.

Did a nslookup and the machine can look up the DNS and get the correct data, what's going on?

Comment: Include the error message (redacted if necessary).

Comment: This is the guts of the warning from the event log.
Event ID: 4007
Message delivery to the host '203.146.237.247' failed while delivering to the remote domain 'raimonland.com' for the following reason: An SMTP protocol error occurred.
 The SMTP verb which caused the error is 'RCPT'.  The response from the remote server is '405 4.7.1 <sales@raimonland.com>: Recipient address rejected: This is Secondary MX from CSLoxinfo. '.

Data:
0000: d7 02 04 c0               ×..À

Comment: Another problem with this domain is there's no reverse dns.

Answer (score 1):

The second MX should only be used when

- the primary / first MX does not respond
- the primary and the secondary have the same preference

You can verify this by using

```
dig ${YOURDOMAIN} MX
```

Also, please not that the secondary MX is refusing the connection with a non-fatal aka. temporary error 4xx.

Comment: Their infrastructure's very different now, I have no idea if they have the same problem.